# Android - Multiple buttons with the same id in different xml, to do the same function

Tags: android, xml, button

I am using 2 popup windows and all buttons are same except 1 button. All buttons will trigger same function except 1 button. I have defined everything. everything is working fine. But as I am new to android and I don't know if this result in some consequences in future. If any of you have encountered any issues with same scenario please let me know so that I can take steps to rectify that.

Comment: put some example code

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: what you mean ? you get the same listener to multiple buttons ?

Comment: use same pop up window since only one button function is changing. you can set the visibility and function that button programatically. having two different pop-ups for similar operations created redundancy

Comment: @MohammedAtif thanks for reply. I will try to set buttons and function of particular button programmatically. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to ask:

Do my resource IDs have to be unique across *all* layouts? Or can I have a button in one layout, and a button in another layout, and both of those buttons perform the same function so I want to give them the same ID, is this legal?

Answer to that question: Yes, you can have the same ID in different XML files, however, you cannot have the same ID multiple times in the *same* XML file.

However, as @Mohammad mentioned in the comments, based on your description there should be no need to create two separate windows when they perform almost the exact same function.

Comment: You got exactly what i wanted to ask.I will try to reduce the redundancy of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using these buttons in fragment/activity you can create a BaseFragment/Activity class. and extend it instead of fragment/AppcompatActivity in your classes.

In BaseFragment/Activity 's oncreate() metod you can bind your buttons and set onclickListener there.